# Is there a way in promql to get all the available label names using thanos api?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, thanos

I have a promql which is giving me the metric result as a whole from the server, but I am interested in filtering and getting results of a specific value, but I am not sure what can be the label name for that value, if I can see all the available names I will be able to at least hit it using trial and error, but without the label names, I am not able to do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While PromQL doesn't provide functionality for returning all the available label names, [Prometheus querying API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) provides such functionality via [/api/v1/labels](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#getting-label-names) handler.

This handler supports optional `start` and `end` query args, which may be used for limiting time range for the returned label names. It also supports `match[]` query args, which may be used for additional filtering on time series. For example, request to `/api/v1/labels?match[]=foo{bar="baz"}` would return only label names for time series matching `foo{bar="baz"}` [time series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#prometheus-querying-api-usage) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

@valyala's answer is helpful for label/metric names. But if you want to get all the values of a label, you can call `/api/v1/label/{YOUR_LABEL_NAME}/values`. See [the docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#querying-label-values). For example:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9090/api/v1/label/instance/values
{
   "status" : "success",
   "data" : [
      "node1",
      "node2",
      "node3",
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`/api/v1/labels` is fine for Prometheus users, but there are [some inconsistent behaviors with Thanos](https://github.com/thanos-io/thanos/issues/3639), so just be careful when using this API